# VSCode editor got errors, while using Haskell installed using Stackage

Tags: haskell, ubuntu-14.04, visual-studio-code, stackage

Recently Installed VS Code in my Ubuntu14.04 . Installed Haskell using Stack.

Getting these errors. Kindly help.

Error: Couldn't start ghc-mod process Error: Command failed: ghc-mod version

Error: Cannot hlint the haskell file. The hlint program was not found. Use the 'haskell.hlint.executablePath' setting to configure the location of 'hlint'
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've installed 2 extensions for vscode, one for linting and one for running ghc-mod, but you don't have hlint or ghc-mod installed.

If you are using [this ghc-mod extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-ghc-mod), make sure you have ghc-mod installed through cabal or through stack.

IF you are using [this linter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.haskell-linter), make sure you have hlint installed through cabal or through stack.

To install with cabal, run:
`cabal install hlint`
and
`cabal install ghc-mod`

To install via stack, see the stack documentation.

Comment: I was told not to install Haskell through Cabal on IRC and was directed to use Stackage since it keeps the system packages and Haskell Libraries separate. Hence I did install Haskell using Stack, but couldn't find Hlint  orGhc-mod documentation in Stack. How to go ahead than. I saw I could do Stack install Hlint. But not sure about GHc-mod

Comment: You need to make sure that `ghc-mod` and `hlint` are available to vscode. You can do this in 2 ways, both of which require you to find the paths to the executables you just installed.

1) add ghc-mod and hlint to your system "path". http://askubuntu.com/questions/381958/add-program-to-path
OR
2) Configure the extensions to tell them where the executable is. The README for both extensions tell you which configuration variable to set.